# Configure ActorSystem in another library

Tags: java, scala, akka, typesafe-config

My application consumes a library which internally initialises an actor system like so

```
ActorSystem("MySys")
```

As a result, the `MySys` actor system uses the default dispatcher.  I want to use a custom dispatcher for this specific actor system instead.  How can I override the dispatcher used by this libraray's actor system in my `application.conf`?

I've already tried doing it like so

```
MySys {
  akka {
    actor {
      default-dispatcher = "my-dispatcher"
    }

    my-dispatcher {
      type = Dispatcher
      executor = "thread-pool-executor"
      thread-pool-executor {
        fixed-pool-size = 85
      }
    }

  }
}
```

However this does not work as a thread dump shows the following output

```
"MySys-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6" #396 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f54501b6000 nid=0x1a6 waiting on condition [0x00007f55285f3000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e4b5b1f0> (a akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinPool)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:2075)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

"MySys-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5" #363 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f545c006800 nid=0x185 waiting on condition [0x00007f5443acf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e4b5b1f0> (a akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinPool)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.idleAwaitWork(ForkJoinPool.java:2135)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:2067)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

"MySys-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4" #362 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f55402e0000 nid=0x184 waiting on condition [0x00007f54445da000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e4b5b1f0> (a akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinPool)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:2075)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

"MySys-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3" #361 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f55402df000 nid=0x183 waiting on condition [0x00007f5539774000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e4b5b1f0> (a akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinPool)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:2075)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

"MySys-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2" #360 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f55402de800 nid=0x182 waiting on condition [0x00007f5440f31000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e4b5b1f0> (a akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinPool)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:2075)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

"MySys-scheduler-1" #359 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f55402dd800 nid=0x181 waiting on condition [0x00007f54440d5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler.waitNanos(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:85)
        at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.nextTick(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:265)
        at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.run(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:235)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no configurations is passed when constructing a new ActorSystem then the root configuration will be used  (i.e. everything inside the akka key)

In the [configuration section of the akka docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/configuration.html) it is recommended that you initialize two different actor systems in the same application by specifically initializing them with separate configs.

```
val config = ConfigFactory.load()
val system1 = ActorSystem("MySys", config.getConfig("MySys"))
val system2 = ActorSystem("my-app", config.getConfig("my-app"))
```

If you can't influence how the first system is created I would suggest just use the default akka region in the configuration for MySys and then namespace the configuration you need for your application.